# Random effect implicitly nested in a fixed effect

Tags: mixed-model

In a very lucid and informative answer to a question about nested versus crossed random effect [Crossed vs nested random effects: how do they differ and how are they specified correctly in lme4?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified/228814) (posted on 8 August 2016) Robert Long used a classes within schools example to illustrate the syntax to use in `lmer()` when the data are coded so that the nesting is "implicit".

In this example `school`, as well as `class` is a random effect.  I need to deal with an example analogous to that in which `school` gets treated as a fixed effect.
I *think* I have the syntax correct, but I would like to have this confirmed (if someone would be so kind).

First, to get the data that Robert Long used:

```
dt <- read.table("http://bayes.acs.unt.edu:8083/BayesContent/class/Jon/R_SC/Module9/lmm.data.txt",
                   header=TRUE, sep=",", na.strings="NA", dec=".", strip.white=TRUE)
```

Now create (as Robert Long did) an "explicitly nested" class factor:

```
dt$classID <- paste(dt$school, dt$class, sep=".")
```

Now I'd like to fit simple examples in which `school` is the only fixed effect predictor.

```
fit.expl <- lmer(extro ~ school + (1 | classID), data = dt)

fit.impl <- lmer(extro ~ school + (1 | class:school), data = dt)
```

Is the latter fit the correct way of dealing with implicit nesting of random effect within a fixed effect?  The two fits seem to agree.  The extractors `fixef()`, `ranef()` and `logLik()` seem to give the same results from the two fits (modulo some differences in labelling).

Are there any Traps for Young Players lurking around that I have failed to take into account?

Comment: Could you please add the link to the question or answer?

Comment: this basically seems correct (`classID` and `class:school` [converted into an interaction variable internally] are equivalent variables); don't have time to write a proper answer at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the two models you specified are equivalent and give identical results. In `extro ~ school + (1 | school:class)`, we produce one fixed intercept, as the score of the reference school, (k - 1) fixed coefficients of `school` for differences among schools relative to the reference school, and random intercepts per class within each school.